# How to iterate through pages in an API query with no page indication?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I've made an api call using this JSON query:

```
import requests 
import json
import pandas as pd

url = ("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?zip=b1+1aa&offset=0&format=json&lon=-1.89999997616&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=500&radius=200.0&fields=&lat=52.4799995422&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=ed49065d620a34c10e1f0f91dd58da2e36547af1")

data = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['results'])
```

So that becomes one dataframe, however, I have 5 more url pages to query which look like this:

```
url2 = ("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?zip=b1+1aa&offset=1&format=json&lon=-1.89999997616&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=500&radius=200.0&fields=&lat=52.4799995422&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=ed49065d620a34c10e1f0f91dd58da2e36547af1")
```

and `url3` is similar just a changing the pages via `offset=2` etc is the key.

I want to know if I can use a for loop to iterate through all these pages.

Comment: is there any documentation on this API? Because just looking at the url i see `page=500`. The other thing you can do is try to see a pattern yourself when you visit other pages. you mentioned seeing the offset pattern. you may want to look at [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) or [.format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) inside of a loop

Comment: you should also properly format your request using a dictionary and feed in the params using the `payload`

Comment: @MattR Thanks. that page=500 is the number of queries you want per page so I Put in that I wanted the max per page.

Answer (score 4):

First do not hardcode the querystring in the url but pass query data to `request` as a dict, ie:

```
url = "https://api.meetup.com/2/groups"
querydict = {
   "zip":"b1+1aa",
   "offset": 0,
   "format":"json",
   "lon":-1.89999997616,
   "category_id": 34,
   "photo-host":"public",
   # etc
   }

response = requests.get(url, params=querydict)
```

Then all you have to do is to loop until you have all the contents you want, updating `querydict["offset"]` on each iteration:

```
url = "https://api.meetup.com/2/groups"
querydict = {
   "zip":"b1+1aa",
   "offset": 0,
   "format":"json",
   "lon":-1.89999997616,
   "category_id": 34,
   "photo-host":"public",
   # etc
   }

while True: 
    response = requests.get(url, params=querydict)
    # check your response status, check the json data
    # etc
    if we_have_enough(response):
        break
    # ok let's fetch next page
    querydict["offset"] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you @bruno desthuilliers. I'm not clear on the `if we_have_enough(response)` part though. Could I ask if you can briefly explain what it is and what do I define the `we_have_enough` variable as?

Comment: That was a just a way to tell that you may want to break out at a given point - either because you don't want the whole dataset or because there's no more data to be fetched. How you test this depends on the exact API (cf the comment about checking the response status and what you got back etc) so it's your job to implement this part.

Answer (score 3):

The Meetup version 2 API responds with a `meta` dictionary that contains a `next` key, you should use that.

```
url = '...'
while url:
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    ... do something with data ...
    url = data['meta'].get('next')
```

Comment: Ok I may be confused but what constitutes, `do something with data` ? Is that a if statement? @Daniel Roseman

Comment: No, it's whatever you actually want to do with the data you've downloaded. Put it into a dataframe, or whatever.